Pacemaker colocation constraint prevent fault-tolerant resource from running
This is a follow-up of this question on super-user which, in hindsight, might have been better in server fault. The problem I have there might be due to the problem I am going to describe here.
I am using pacemaker to manage a raid5 device whose volumes are distributed among 3 nodes and exported via iscsi. Pacemaker elects one of these 3 nodes to import all these devices and assemble the raid device locally. Since this is a raid5`, the device can work when at most one of the volumes is down, and so pacemaker should keep activating the corresponding resource even if a whole node is down. The whole structure is represented below:
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|>----- host1-host3 ------------------------|
|                                                                         |                                           |
|                                               [require-all=false]       |                                           |
|                                                             |           |                                           |
| target-host1 - lun-host1 -|-|-- iscsi-host1-direct-clone ---|           |                                           |
|                           | |>- iscsi-host1-indirect-clone -|- host1 -|-|---------------------|>--- host1-host2 ----|
|                           |>--- iscsi-host1-sync-clone -----|         |                       |                     |
|                                                                       |                       |                     |
| |--------------------------------------------------------------------<|                       |                     |
| |                                                                                             |                     |
| |                                               [require-all=false]                           |                     |
| |                                                             |                               |                     |
| | target-host2 - lun-host2 -|-|-- iscsi-host2-direct-clone ---|                               |                     |-raid
| |                           | |>- iscsi-host2-indirect-clone -|- host2 -----|-----------------|----|                |
| |                           |>--- iscsi-host2-sync-clone -----|             |                      |                |
| |                                                                           |                      |                |
| |---------------------------------------------------------------------|>----|>- host1-host2-host3 ------------------|
|                                                                       |                            |                |
|                                               [require-all=false]     |                            |                |
|                                                             |         |                            |                |
| target-host3 - lun-host3 -|-|-- iscsi-host3-direct-clone ---|         |                            |                |
|                           | |>- iscsi-host3-indirect-clone -|- host3 -|-|--------------------------|>- host2-host3 -| 
|                           |>--- iscsi-host3-sync-clone -----|           |                                           |
|                                                                         |                             [require-all=false]
|------------------------------------------------------------------------<|

Resource host1 is set to be started after at least one of iscsi-host1-direct-clone, iscsi-host1-indirect-clone and iscsi-host1-indirect-clone is started, with an order constraint I create as follows:
pcs constraint order set host1-direct host1-indirect host1-sync require-all=false sequential=false set host1

I reproduce the same order constraints for host2 and host3. Resource host1-host2 requires both resources host1 and host2 to be active:
pcs constraint order set host1 host2 sequential=false set host1-host2

And resources host1-host3 and host2-host3 follow the same principle. I also have host1-host2-host3 which is active when all nodes are onlines and all iscsi devices are properly exported and imported. Finally, raid requires at least one of host1-host2, host1-host3, host2-host3 or host1-host2-host3 to start.
pcs constraint order set host1-host2 host1-host3 host2-host3 host1-host2-host3 require-all=false sequential=false set raid

I also need to make sure that whichever node runs resource raid, also managed to import at least 2 iscsi devices. My best attempts to do it are the following set of constraints:
pcs constraint colocation set raid set host1-host2 host1-host3 host2-host3 host1-host2-host3 sequential=false
pcs constraint colocation set host1-host2-host3 set host1 host2 host3
pcs constraint colocation set host1-host2 set host1 host2
pcs constraint colocation set host1-host3 set host1 host3
pcs constraint colocation set host2-host3 set host2 host3
pcs constraint colocation set host1 set iscsi-host1-direct-clone iscsi-host1-indirect-clone iscsi-host1-sync-clone
pcs constraint colocation set host2 set iscsi-host2-direct-clone iscsi-host2-indirect-clone iscsi-host2-sync-clone
pcs constraint colocation set host3 set iscsi-host3-direct-clone iscsi-host3-indirect-clone iscsi-host3-sync-clone

The problem is, pacemaker refuses to start resource raid if any of the node is down. For example, if node 3 is down, then all iscsi-host3-*-clone resources are failed, which means host3 is stopped and so are host1-host3, host2-host3 and host1-host2-host3. This is fine as far as order constraints are concerned, but pacemaker seems to refuse to place resource raid anywhere before it knows where host1-host3, host2-host3 and host1-host2-host3 are placed, because of the first colocation constraint above, and this even if I use the set option sequential=false. I seem to miunderstand here. I read on [clusterlab doc](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/2.1/Pacemaker_Explained/html/constraints.html#colocating-sets-of-resources) that if I user sequential="false", then pacemaker will place the colocated resources in other sets of the constraint into the same node as either resource in the set annotated with sequential="false". The documentation is actually unclear whether this means only one of these resources (i.e., in the sequential="false" set) needs to be active, or whether pacemaker just waits for all resources to be active and only then picks one at random as node colocation reference. In the latter case, this is really inconvenient as that this defeats the purpose of managing fault-tolerant resources.
Please give advice on how I can setup colocation constraints that still allows one node to fail and the fault-tolerant raid device to still run.

Clusterlab doc mentions "mandatory placement" with score=INFINITY that prevents placing ready-to-run resources constrained to be colocated to other resources unable to run. The reason is that Pacemaker must first know on what node does the resource of reference runs before taking a decision about the depending resource. I still find unclear the case of a set colocation constraint with the sequential=false setting, as exposed in my question.
Clusterlab describes advisory placement, i.e., constraints with option score=<some integer> tagged to, as opposed to the default score=INFINITY value. When applied to the first and the 3 last colocation constraints of my question, Pacemaker seems to be finally willing to place resource raid even if any one of the iscsi resource failed. I am a little unsure about the goodness of this solution, as it looks like now that if Pacemaker finds a compelling enough reason to violate this constraint, then it will do so with no second thought. Does anyone know any solution that still employs mandatory placement?
